# How to keep user logged in with Auth0 when Flutter app is offline?

Tags: flutter, auth0

I have a Flutter app that uses Auth0 for authentication. It works fine if a user has an internet connection, but they can't log in when in offline mode. Is it as simple as storing a boolean with SharedPreferences if they have previously logged in?

Answer (score 0):

You can save the auth info by using sharePrefences(or GetStorage).
And load the saved auth data when the app is starting.

Check the pub info below.

sharePref :  https://pub.dev/packages/shared_preferences

getStorage : https://pub.dev/packages/get_storage